# I am attempting to fix responsive issues with a particular website but cannot seem to get the footer widgets

Tags: css, wordpress

I am attempting to fix responsive issues with a particular website but cannot seem to get the footer widgets in place at 769px: https://aquatiere.co.uk/

In particular the last row widget buttons are not resizing to fit into the footer.

Please assist. I have tried all the classes and IDs related to those buttons but with no luck.

Comment: To make it easier for us to help you, can you create a working code snippet within your question for the specific parts you're having trouble with? Including what you want the buttons to do at the specific screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the widths of `.so-widget-sow-button-flat-e0300fa09137 .ow-button-base a` and `.ow-button-base.ow-button-align-left` for the media 769px

See below:

```
.so-widget-sow-button-flat-e0300fa09137 .ow-button-base a {
    width: 100%;
}

.ow-button-base.ow-button-align-left {
    width: 100%; !important;
}
```

You also need to remove the left alignments for these:

```
#pgc-w5875dc6eb4286-0-0 {
    position: relative!important;
    left: 35px!important;
}

.panel-grid-cell {
    position: relative!important;
    left: 20px!important;
}
```

But this is causing issues for your other elements, I'd suggest reworking your css.

See screenshot with the above done:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciate your comment and assistance and I will try these techniques :)